# Expanding the range dynamically on Inserting rows

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, named-ranges

I have an excel sheet with Insert Rows button.

I have divided the my template sheet into three section of ranges (Finance, Operations, Technology),with each range consisting of two rows now. When user insert rows( user can insert as many rows he want in a go), all those rows should be inserted in the range user is currently in.

So basically, it is resizing. But am unable to find a generic code that will work for my different section of ranges.

Is there a way I can define dynamic ranges using the name manager in Excel sheet and make my current code work with it? Please help.

```
enter code here
 Sub Insert_rows()

Dim xCount As Integer
LableNumber:
xCount = Application.InputBox("Number of Rows", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 1)
If xCount < 1 Then
    MsgBox "the entered number of rows is error, please enter again", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    'GoTo LableNumber
End If

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(xCount - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(xCount, 0)).EntireRow.Validation.Delete
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: How does your code not do what you want?

Comment: It does not expand the range when new rows are inserted. suppose my range is A2:I7. When a new row is added, the existing range should expand it as A2:J7

Comment: sorry New range should be A2:I8 , AN EXTRA ROW ADDED

Comment: Are you using named ranges?

Comment: Yes but it is not dynamic, I am not sure how to make it dynamic

Comment: Have you considered using Tables? https://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html